# How to change JDK version for an Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I need to write a project that's only compatible with Java 1.5. I have Java 1.6 installed. Is there some form of backwards compatibility to get Eclipse to compile with 1.5?

Do I have to install Java 1.5 to get it to show here? Or maybe there is another way?

[image].

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Click on the **Add Library** button. It brings your [screen](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-add_new_jre.htm) to point to the Java location.

Select "**Directory**", button right besides JRE home and point to the installed folder location.

Even though you want to just 1.5 compiler project, you can achieve it by changing compiler settings in Eclipse instead of removing 1.6 JRE and add 1.5 JRE.

```
GOTO -->JAVA--Compiler---> and change compiler level to `1.5` instead of `1.6`
```

As davidfmatheson suggested,

Just be careful, especially if you're setting this up for a team of people to work on. If anyone uses anything that is new or changed in 1.6, it will compile, but not run in an environment with JRE 1.5.

Comment: Maybe the question was misunderstood... do I need to install JDK 1.5? If I follow your instructions I still have to browse for the 1.5 folder. Is it fine to have two JDKs installed alongside?

Comment: Unless you have restriction that your files should be compiled for version 1.5 (or) any libraries don't support 1.6, it is not required have 1.5.

Comment: Even though you want to just 1.5 compiler project, you can achieve it by changing compiler settings in eclipse.

Comment: Ok, so if I got to Java > Compiler > Compliance Level and set it to 1.5, Compile a JAR and then run it on a device supporting only 1.5, it should work?

Comment: Yes. It should work without any issues. Before doing jar, make sure compliance level set to 1.5 always.

Comment: Just be careful, especially if you're setting this up for a team of people to work on.  If anyone uses anything that is new or changed in 1.6, it will compile, but not run in an environment with JRE 1.5.

Comment: @davidfmatheson: I think when you try to use 1.6 feature and set 1.5 compilation level, eclipse flags it (I need to double check when I am at my machine). This is valid comment, if you are right.

Comment: @Nambari My Eclipse Juno environment does not give me any indication that something is amiss.  Take a project with JDK 1.6, set the compliance to 1.5 and add the line `ArrayDeque<String> doubleEndedQueue = new ArrayDeque<String>();` to a `main` method.  `ArrayDeque` is a new `java.util` collection type in 1.6.  Now try to run that with a 1.5 JRE.  It will error out.

Comment: @RomanC It is bytecode, but potentially with types that the older JRE doesn't recognize.  Try my use case.  You'll see it causes an error.

Comment: @davidfmatheson: If that is the case I agree with your comment.

Answer (score 42):

Click on the *Window* tab in Eclipse, go to *Preferences* and when that window comes up, go to *Java* → *Installed JREs* → *Execution Environment* and choose JavaSE-1.5. You then have to go to *Compiler* and set the *Compiler compliance level*.

[image: Changing JRE]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, close to getting to the answer, compliance level was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 31):

Right click project -> Properties -> **Java Build Path** -> select **JRE System Library** click **Edit** and select **JDK** or **JRE** after then click **Java Compiler** and select  **Compiler compliance level** to **1.8**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's Java 1.8 got to do with the question?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using maven build tool then add the below properties to it and doing a maven update will solve the problem

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: In my case I need to setup this on pom.xml in order to works.

Answer (score 4):

In the preferences section under Java -> Installed JREs click the Add button and navigate to the 1.5 JDK home folder.  Then check that one in the list and it will become the default for all projects:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See the page *[Set Up JDK in Eclipse](https://techiedan.com/set-up-jdk-in-eclipse/)*. From the add button you can add a different version of the JDK...

Answer (score 3):

The JDK (JAVA_HOME) used to launch Eclipse is not necessarily the one used to compiled your project.

To see what JRE *you* can select for your project, check the preferences:

*General* → *Java Installed JRE*

By default, if you have not added any JRE, the only one declared will be the one used to launched Eclipse (which can be defined in your [**eclipse.ini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)).

You can add any other JRE you want, including one compatible with your project.

After that, you will need to check in your project properties (or in the general preferences) what JRE is used, with what compliance level:

[image]
<sub>(source: [standartux.fr](http://www.standartux.fr/public/Java/Preferences.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse - specific Project change JDK Version -

If you want to change any jdk version of A specific project than you have to click ---> Project --> JRE System Library --> Properties ---> Inside Classpath Container (JRE System Library) change the Execution Environment to which ever version you want e.g. 1.7 or 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

As I was facing this issue minutes ago, in case you are trying to open an existing project in an environment with a newer JDK, make sure you pdate the JDK version in Project Properties -> Project Facets -> Java.