# Grails requires jdk

Tags: java, eclipse, grails

I have installed several jre's and jdk's on my computer.

Today I set up `grails version 2.3.4`.

I have downloaded and installed the grails plugin on a new eclipse kepler.

However, when I start eclipse I get:

[image]

How to change to an `jdk` in eclipse?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

As you can see the jdk should be properly configured:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project

Comment: @baxxabit where is this option in `eclipse kepler`? Can`t find it ;(

Comment: I use Intellij idea, but you can try:

settings and in input fill jdk or java @user1000

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-add_new_jre.htm maybe it would be helpful

Comment: if you still can't find http://i.stack.imgur.com/eCVwC.png @user1000

Comment: @baxxabit pls see my update! As you can see I have installed all the libs that I need... However I get the same exception as before...

Comment: I see several JRE's in your configuration, but no JDK's...

Comment: @GijsOvervliet Thx for your answer! However, thats not true, in my update you can see that these two are `jdk`s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the path of the eclipse-vm to a jdk (i.e. the vm with which eclipse is started) in the eclipse ini like described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value%3a_Windows_Example).