# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openbravo/base/ConnectionProviderContextListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu, unsupported-class-version

I am using Eclipse Indigo running on Ubuntu and I am trying to set up a Tomcat server following the last part of this guide:

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_setup_Eclipse_IDE

My problem is that when I try to boot the Tomcat server I get this error (Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start.):

[image]

My console looks like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openbravo/base/ConnectionProviderContextListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (no puedo cargar clase org.openbravo.base.ConnectionProviderContextListener)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2822)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadClassAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1078)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    ... 6 more
```

What can I do? I tryed adding tomcat-juli.jar to my server classpath, which is the main solution I have found but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

Thanks to the answer Tomcat starts but does not make the resource available.
There are compilation errors in the Openbravo projects as well.

[image]
Eclipse Openbravo Project

[image]
Resource not available at localhost:8080/openbravo/

[image]
Tomcat Configuration in Eclipse

---

2nd EDIT:

[image]

Deploy Tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your JDK version. The classes were probably compiled in a JDK version higher to yours.

Edit: Probably it is JDK/JRE 8.

Comment: In my .bashrc I have export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/Documentos/jdk1.8.0_05 Could eclipse be running another version of Java? How can I check it?

Comment: Change the JDK version for your project. You may refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project

Comment: When I do so I only get options up to 1.7, not a trace of 1.8.

Comment: This helped: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: Glad you got it resolved by yourself. I thought you already had JDK 8 installed. But I fail to understand why a opensource project would compile with JDK 8 in its early days. It probably is a bad move, unless they are using some Java 8 specific features.

Comment: Do you know why now, even though the server does start I get a 404 Openbravo resource not found?

Comment: I guess the application is not deployed. Check the server tab, in your screenshot it is the first one. There you should have a tree like view of the applications deployed (not very sure though). Also check the logs for the string 'openbravo', if it is deployed or an attempt was made to deploy it, there should be some mention of it in the logs.

Comment: I added the deploy tree you mentioned as a picture. The folder logs at tomcat folder is empty at the moment.