# Lambda expression in java not working

Tags: java, lambda

I'm tryig to make a lambda expresion for an ActionListener, but it's giving me an IllegalStart of expression, what i'm trying to run so far looks like this:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton boton = new JButton("Lambda Button");
    boton.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println("Hello World!"));
    frame.add(boton);

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

On the other hand, when i use this code instead:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton boton = new JButton("Lambda Button");
    boton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Hello World!");
                                }
                                }   );
    frame.add(boton);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

It works perfectly fine,

Initially i tought the issue could be the version of java i'm running, but i just updated and keeps doing the same, when i do a java -version i gives me the following:

> java -version
>   java version "1.8.0_45"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

So, as far as i know it have a version compatible with lambda expression but not succed on making them work, any ideas or suggestion of what could he happening ?

EDIT:
When i try to compile i get this:

```
Prueba.java:57: error: illegal start of expression
            boton.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println("Hello World !"));
                                           ^1 error
```

EDIT2:
I'm not using any IDE, im compiling from the command line

Comment: What IDE are you using? Are you sure the JDK for your project is defined to Java 8 JDK home?

Comment: In your IDE, are you compiling your code as 1.8? (in Eclipse: project properties > java compiler > JDK compliance).  Regardless of which JRE you are using to run it, you still need to compile it as 1.8 too.

Comment: Im not using any IDE, im running it from the command line...

Comment: @user4792574 You run the command line from the same terminal as `java -version` ?

Comment: yes, i compile from the command line

Comment: also, verify that "event" is not the name of an already defined local variable or current method parameter. Lambda parameter names are defined in the same scope as their enclosing environment.

Comment: @OlivierCroisier The error would be "variable event is already defined".

Comment: what is your javac version? `javac -version`

Comment: java -version java version "1.8.0_45" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

javac -version:
javac 1.7.0_13


Could be because the compiler doesn't have the same version as the JRE ?

Comment: @user4792574 You are compiling with java 7, this is why it does not work. As I mentionned in my edit.

Comment: not necessarily, yes; what operating system are you using?

Comment: @flo what do you mean by "not necessarily" ? How could someone compile java 8 code with a java 7 compiler ?

Comment: ok, perfect, the issue was with the version of javac, installed the last version now and runs perfectly, thank you very much guys, you've all been of a great help.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I meant a Java 8 JRE does not necessarily mean a JAVA 8 javac.

Comment: @flo Oh I misunderstood your comment, make more sense now :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit**

As per your comments, you are not using any IDE and your `javac` version is 1.7. You need to compile with java 8, else the lambda won't be recognized.

---

**I will keep this part in my answer as it may solve the problem for someone else, even if this was not the solution in this case.**

Your lambda is perfectly fine. The error is probably due to a wrong compiler compliance level setting.

If you use eclipse, refer to this post for how to change the compiler compliance level :

[How to change JDK version for an Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project)

If you use Netbeans, remember (this is something many people forget) that you have to set both the `source` and `libraries` target to 8 if you want it to function properly.

---

**Source** 
[image]

---

**Libraries**

[image]

Calling `java -version` from the command-line does not mean that the proper library is set in the IDE, so you have to verify this.

If you use any other IDE then google *"How to change jdk version on YourIDE"*.

Answer (score 5):

And if you are using intellij by any chance, please make sure Project language level is set to 8 - Lambdas..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`boton.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println("Hello World!"));` - Lambda Expression is perfectly fine. You are passing event to actionPerformed method of ActionListener functional interface which will be mapped while compilation of code using java 8 compiler.

Please check your java version.