# Steps to Migrate Code from Java 6 to Java 7 using eclipse

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

I have the existing codebase which runs on java6, but the current requirement is to upgrade the Java from **java6 to java 7**, Can anyone please let me know the steps, how can i upgrade it using eclipse(because i am using eclipse as IDE)?.

Comment: Step 1: just set the JDK to Java 7 and make sure that the project is not set to Java 6 compatibility, then check if something breaks. If not, try to run.

Comment: Just in case the mild sarcasm is lost in that comment: What I'm saying is that at this point you don't even know you need to migrate anything so you're asking about something which may be entirely a non-issue. Try before you ask.

Comment: Gimby, just want to tel you that. I will follow the steps as like below: <br/> 1. Uninstall Jav6 from system 2. Install Java 7 and 3. Point to Java 7. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading *code* requires almost nothing, as Java 7 is backwards compatible with Java 6 except for a [few things](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities), mostly behavioral and in the standard library. And as said [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/migrating_from_java_se_6), it should mostly just work:

> What do I need to do?
>
> Option 1 – “Just run”

Upgrading your eclipse *project* has been asked and answered several times, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project).