# Why can I compile this code via command line but not with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

These lines of code

```
    System.out.println(
        Stream.of("adam", "bob", "adrian", "brian")
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        x -> x.substring(0,1),        //1
                        Collectors.joining("-")))
    );
```

compile fine when using `javac` via command line, but when I try to compile in Eclipse I get this error

> The method substring(int, int) is undefined for the type CharSequence

How can Eclipse interfere with the compiler? Doesn't an IDE just use `javac.exe`?

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1, with Oracle jdk1.8.0_45

Comment: Works for me in Eclipse Mars 4.5.1. Just upgrade.

Comment: Is it possible that your Eclipse project uses a different version of Java for compilation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between javac and the Eclipse compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler)

Comment: The general solution to your question is: understand the variables in the equation. In that case: what version of Java comes into play on the command line (something that knows Java 8) ... and what version of Java is supported by your eclipse (probably not Java 8; so guess you are running on Luna(?) or older?!

Comment: If the OP wasn't using Java 8, they'd have a lot more errors than the missing method, since it would also be unable to resolve Collectors, Stream, `->`, etc.

Comment: You may upgrade the jdk for your working [project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: I can confirm this doesn't compile on Luna (4.4) with Java 8, but works on Mars.

Comment: Also, `CharSequence` doesn't have a `substring(int, int)` method, it's got `subSequence(int, int)`.  I think the real question here is why x is being treated as a `CharSequence` and not a `String`.

Comment: This also compiles fine for Eclipse Mars 4.5.0. Seems this is only a Luna (or before) problem.

Comment: Tell us the version of Eclipse you use.

Comment: @Jägermeister I added Eclipse and jdk version

Answer (score 4):

In the first place you should make sure that this isn't a syntax error.
Change your code to look like this:

```
x -> ((String) x).substring(0,1)
```

Besides making sure that you use a fully Java 8 compatible version of Eclipse, you should check if you allow Eclipse to use Java 8 language features.

[image]

[image]

If you didn't specify the correct version of JRE you can change it like described here: [How to change JDK version for an Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project?lq=1)

Comment: Already checked that, JRE is the right one. At this point, shouldn't this be considered a bug?

Comment: As soon as you are sure this does not work on a clean install of Eclipse and that your code does not contain any errors. I had to change your code to `x -> ((String) x).substring(0,1)` in order to make it run on my STS 3.7.1

Comment: That's it! You don't need any change to successfully compile it with Oracle javac.exe

Comment: Perhaps you could create a new answer and ask if it is possible to achieve the same without this rather ugly cast.

Comment: To avoid the cast you can also declare the type of `x` like this: `(String x) -> x.substring(0,1)`. This will help the compiler while also preserving type safety. Nevertheless, this looks like a bug in the eclipse < 4.5 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved in Eclipse as of 4.5 Milestone 3, most likely via [bug 437444](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=437444). That change combines some bug fixes with [incorporating several JLS changes](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=437444#c162) made after the release of Java 8.

We could discuss whether the example was actually legal Java 8 before the spec changes (previously inference wasn't allowed to use some information from nested lambda bodies), but I hope just updating to Eclipse 4.5.1 will make everybody happy.