# Robotium Error message

Tags: automation

After click on the New test for robotium recoder I am getting error message for Please select the root Java JDK folder.
My JAVA_PATH,HOME_PATH,CLASSPATH are saved properly in the environmetn variables.
I am using windows 10.(64-bit)[Screenshot for issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWSIb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote about

> JAVA_PATH,HOME_PATH,CLASSPATH

Is %JAVA_HOME% configured correctly?

You can simply verify it using cmd.exe

```
java -version
```

If yes - add JDK for eclipse.
This article should help:
[How to Change JDK version for an eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project)

UPD:
Here steps for Robotion with screenshots with your issue resolved:
[Blog](http://nadimsaker.blogspot.com/2015/04/robotium-how-to-automate-android.html)