# Bukkit - Plugin not loading - major.minor error

Tags: java, bukkit

I made a bukkit plugin that for some reason doesn't work. 
Here are some things I think will help:
1. The plugin doesn't appear in /plugins
2. The console is giving a major.minor error
3. The commands don't give any error; they just say `unknown command`.
Here is my code:

```
package me.Orion31.broadcaster;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("Enabled Broadcaster by Orion version " + getDescription().getVersion());
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(false);
    } 
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("Disabled Broadcaster!");
    }
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bc") || command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("broadcast")) {
            if (player.hasPermission("broadcast.bc")) {
                if (args.length == 1) {
                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',
                            getConfig().getString("Tag") + getConfig().getString("Color") + " " + args[0]));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Invalid Arguments!");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Usage: /broadcast <message>");
                    return true;
                }
            } else
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You don't have permissions!");
            return true;
        } else if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bcset")) {
            if (args.length == 2) {
                if (player.hasPermission("broadcast.bc")) {
                    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("tag")) {
                        getConfig().set("Tag", args[1]);
                        saveConfig();
                    } else if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("color")){
                        getConfig().set("Color", args[1]);
                        saveConfig();
                    }
                } else
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You don't have permissions!");

            } else {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Invalid usage!");
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Usage: /bctag tag,color <new value>");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Plugin.yml:

```
name: Broadcaster
main: me.Orion31.broadcaster.Main
version: 1.0
commands:
   broadcast:
      description: Broadcast a message to the whole server!
      usage: /broadcast <message>
   bcset:
      description: Change the properties of the broadcaster.
      usage: /bcset tag,color <new value>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How did you export it?
Do the messages apper in the console, such as "Enabled broadcaster by..."?

Comment: @Kerooker I am using eclipse.  There is no message about this plugin.  It is in the /plugins directory

Comment: Your code is working for me, maybe you're exporting it wrongly, therefore it's not a plugin jar file...
Also, are you remembering to reopen your server?

Comment: @Kerooker how do you think I should export it?  I am on eclipse.  And yes the server is on.

Comment: @Kerooker I tried exporting in Java 7 and Java 8  Now i'm getting a major.minor error

Comment: @Orion31 I think your "major.minor" error probably refers to unsupported major.minor version, which means you have compiled some files that are not supported due to their file version(e.g. too high). Also, you can have a look at the [official tutorial](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial).

Comment: @Cnly I compiled the whole thing in Java 7, the same version i needed to use to get my other plugin to work.  I also tried Java 8.  Here is the console error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/20605362/

Comment: @Orion31 Your _server_ is using a version under 8. So _don't_ use Java 8 for your plugins. Also, can you include your .jar file structure in your post? And is there anything in the server.log like `[Broadcaster] Loading Broadcaster` or `[Broadcaster] Enabling Broadcaster v1.0`?

Comment: @Orion31 the problem I see must be related to the way you're exporting, because your exact code compiles and runs on my home server. Maybe this video is of help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6V0AmwgH7QU

Comment: @Cnly I think this is what you mean by jar structure: there is `plugin.yml` and `config.yml`.  It is in the `/plugins` folder.  The folder for it doesn't generate, and the console isn't giving me anything else besides from errors for this plugin.

Comment: What are the errors then?

Comment: @Kerooker I am getting an error that says: `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: me/Orion31/broadcaster/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

Comment: That error comes from your project having a Java version higher than your server supports. To fix that, you must change your Eclipse's project to use a different JDK, with a lower version. You're probrably exporting with Java 8, try exporting with Java 7

Comment: @Kerooker tried downloading and exporting with Java 7.  Same error as before.

Comment: @orion The major.minor error must be gone if you use a diferent JDK. You have to change your project's JDK to an earlier version

Comment: @Kerooker I tried using JDK 7, but it still won't work.  I might rewrite it.

Comment: How did you actually changed the version, and how did you export? You might be doing it wrong. Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project

Comment: Try exporting it using JDK 6

Answer (score 0):

Simple error, even myself forget to do it often.

Change `public class Main extends JavaPlugin` to `public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements CommandExecutor`.

Once you do that you should be good.

Comment: Not necessary, as JavaPlugin already loads as a CommandExecutor