# How to run STS on Java version 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite, ubuntu-14.10

I need to  run eclipse(java 1.7) and  STS 3.8.1  ( java 1.8) but if i select the  java 7 as default i am getting error in the  STS 3.8.1.
 I am using `OS : ubuntu 14.10`

```
Error  : Version 1.7.0_80 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.8 or greater is required.
```

Or I select `java 1.8` as default eclipse is not working fine.

My requirement is  to build a Project using `java 1.7  with STS.`  and latest version 3.8.1 doesnot  support the  java 1.7.

and i try to search which `version of STS support 1.7` but i am not getting any answer .

Comment: If you only need Java 7 for building a Project, you can Change the Java Version inside of your eclipse/STS for only this Project in the Project properties

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project for more informations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

I just set the jdk in the  alternative jre value .

Answer (score 8):

This question is old, but for anyone looking at this in the future who can't install Java 8 or otherwise can't use the workaround in the other answer - 3.8.0 was the first version requiring Java 1.8, while 3.7.3 still plays nice with only Java 1.7.

Comment: This helps a lot.

Answer (score 7):

If you came to this page because you searched for the same error but wanted a different option, you can try updating the STS.ini configuration settings (e.g. at /sts-win32-x86_64/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.3.RELEASE/ folder) with two lines at the top as follows. The second line is path to your Java 8 installation.

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javaw.exe
```

**Original**:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1200m
```

**Updated**:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1200m
```

Comment: Splitting hairs here, but shouldn't `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javaw.exe` be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javaw.exe`? Back slashes, not forward slashes.

Comment: You are not splitting hairs JeremyCanfield, both should work. I think I am just used to forward slashes to avoid escaping characters.

Answer (score 1):

It is asking for jdk 1.8 to open and run the STS (eclipse). It will still allow you to build your project/code with whatever JDK version you want.

Install jdk1.8, set your JAVA_HOME and PATH env variables so that 1.8 becomes your default jdk. After this your should be able to open STS. Then setup project and set project's JDK to 1.7 or whatever you want.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The STS 3.8.1 all-in-one distribution is based on Eclipse v4.6 which required Java 1.8 to start it.
As @Jens mentioned, you can to Open `Windows` -> `Preferences`. Then open tree node `Java` > `Installed JREs`. After adding a new JRE/JDK, you can set it as default or delete others items.

Another option: if you have installed Eclipse 4.5, please visit https://spring.io/tools/sts/all

1. Install STS 3.8.1 via **Update Sites**: open `Help` -> `Install New Software...`. Just paste update site URL in the Wizard.
2. If you prefer install it offline, you can download STS **Update Site Archives**. Clicking the `Add...` button in the same Wizard, select the folder of unpacked zip file.