# Spring perspective is not showing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am trying to develop a spring boot application. I am using eclipse IDE. I installed STS from eclipse marketplace. But i cannot open the Spring perspective, and also i cannot create spring project (Option is not showing up in new project). 
I then uninstalled STS and installed all the required softwares from Install new Software(http://dist.sp...). Still facing the same problem. Please help me out solving this issue.

Comment: Facing the same issue, using Java 1.8 + Neon3 + installed STS plugin from Eclipse Marketplace. Cannot find Spring Perspective.

Answer (score 3):

I solved mine by changing the Java version in my eclipse.ini file.

So in eclipse.ini :

```
Look for(
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
)

Change to(
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
)
```

And that worked.

Answer (score 2):

I change the windows java_home environment variable to jdk1.8，and the spring setting in preferences and the spring perspective show.
[This(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761992/how-to-run-sts-on-java-version-1-7) may helps to understand the relation between sts and the jdk version

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Spring option was not showing up. I manually rebooted Eclipse, and then it showed up.
One more thing, I noticed there was one more installation dialog open behind Eclipse. I had to close that manually too. So after package installation, Eclipse failed to reboot itself, I think.
I am using Eclipse Neon 1 on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall sts and again install from marketplace. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with STS4, Spring Tool Suite no longer includes the Spring Perspective

See here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/23

Answer (score 0):

Though we cannot find the 'Spring Perspective'. 
Right Click inside Project explorer -> New-> Others -> Search 'Spring Starter project', We can get the Spring Starter Project. And go ahead to create SpringBoot project