# Spring Integration with Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

[image]
I just started Spring tutorial.I am using eclipse luna 4.4.2 
I have successfully integrated STS suite with my eclipse.My Problem is I cant see Spring tab in perspective ...It may sounds silly...bear me plz

Comment: hard to tell what exactly is going wrong, but I would recommend to download the Spring Tool Suite distribution from https://spring.io/tools. It contains a ready-to-use Eclipse distribution with all the Spring components already installed. In addition to that I would recommend to use a more recent Eclipse version than Luna (4.4.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these links can help:

[Spring perspective is not showing in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366803/spring-perspective-is-not-showing-in-eclipse)

https://dzone.com/articles/springide-using-spring-eclipse