# eclipse the project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried to find solution for my question but seems like no solution have worked yet.
Just to mention, im using latest jdk and jre version.

So when im making new java project then i get these 2 errors, its not matter which source i load, all of them gives same error which is weird.

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.util.function.Predicate. Fix the build path then try building this project    oosbrut     Unknown Java Problem

The type java.util.function.Predicate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    GlobalObjects.java  /oosbrut/src/org/brutality/world/objects    line 1  Java Problem
```

`Line 1  : package org.brutality.world.objects;`

PS: I have tried all , cleaning project, refreshing, re-opening eclipse etc , also i have removed all libraries and reloaded all of them again.

Would be great if someone can help me out.

Comment: what java/jdk version you are using for project?

Comment: jdk1.8.0_131 and  jre1.8.0_131.

Comment: Is the compile level for your Java project set to Java 8 as well? What about the .project file to give some more information on your project setup?

Comment: im not sure what you mean but here how it looks like : http://prnt.sc/f2by22 (really never had to touch these settings so idk much about em).

Comment: source project file : https://www.upload.ee/files/6959689/.project.html and client project file : https://www.upload.ee/files/6959697/.project.html

Comment: No one able to help? :/

Comment: @RaivoP. `java.util.function.Predicate` is introduced in java 8 and in case of your project, compiler level is set to 1.7 as per `prnt.sc/f2by22` hence the error.Change compiler level to  1.8 and then build your project. more on setting jdk for eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project