# Eclipse doesn't recognize 'default' keyword

Tags: java, eclipse, default

I am trying to make a simple Interpreter for Java.
Out teacher gave us a code to modify to reach our goal, but Eclipse doesn't like the keyword 'default'

[image]

The error is "Syntax error on token "default", delete this token"

I think it depends from my JDK version of java, this is what i am using

[image]

What should i modify?

Edit: i have Java 8 installed, but Eclipse doesn't allow me to change my compilance level over 1.7

[image]

Comment: upgrade to java-8

Comment: *"i have Java 8 installed, but Eclipse doesn't allow me to change my compilance level over 1.7"* - Because that not Java 8. A directory called "Java 8" doesn't mean that Java 8 is actually inside. Check what `[path to java]/jre/bin/java -version` is telling you.

Comment: stefano@berti-casa:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin$ ./java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
I think this is Java 8, but i am not sure i am using this in Eclipse, how can i check it?

Comment: The path is already visible in the second picture.

Comment: So i am using the right version of JRE, the problem could be the JDK?

Comment: What release of Eclipse is this? You need Luna (4.4), Mars (4.5) or Neon (4.6) to support Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Default Methods introdced only in Java 8

Download jdk 8 and use it in Eclipse

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using JRE JavaSE-1.7:

[image: JRE]

This JRE isis prior to Java 8, where `default` keyword has been introduced for defining default implementations of interface methods.

[Switch JRE version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12588537/335858) to 1.8 to fix this problem.

Comment: @StefanoBerti Did you follow directions at the link on how to switch JDK?

Comment: Yes, but in the options for the Compiler Compilance Level i have just 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, there isn't 1.8

Comment: @StefanoBerti Does the portion of screen on your second screen shot shows 1.8 now? There is a link to Eclipse inside the accepted answer that I linked above, you need to follow it to change JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just can not use/define an ***default method***, because those are available since java 8 (and your project is using java7)... so you need to move the project to java8.

Oracle can help you, check this here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html

is the **What's New in JDK 8** part, 3rd element in the list....

- *Default methods enable new functionality to be added to the interfaces of libraries and ensure binary compatibility with code written for older versions of those interfaces*.