# maven project build shows Compilation failure

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I am creating a web application using spring mvc with eclipse as my IDE and every time I build my project I keep getting getting the following :- `Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/dev1/project/GeoVision/src/main/java/com/mmi/controllers/GeoJsonToShp.java diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5`
I have changed the java build path and set it to latest JRE and even then the error won't go.

Also, **I am  able to run the project on server**?

Please suggest what is it that I have to change to successfully build my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need to configure the compile level in IDE settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project)

[Or configure the maven file (probably this rather than eclipse)](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: In the 1st link as it suggested to click on the add library option and select directory option, in my case there is no directory option seems to appear?

Comment: That is unrelated to your issue,` "GOTO -->JAVA--Compiler---> and change compiler level to `1.5` instead of `1.6`"` is the one related to you. However i really think that its most likely the pom (maven file) configuration