# Eclipse is asking for an older version of JDK, how to change it to a newer one?

Tags: eclipse

I have imported a project from others. They use an older version of JDK. But I have a newer version jdk1.8.0_201 installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201.

Eclipse is showing errors:

```
"Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'PPP-WEB'.
The archive: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/lib/tools.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
The archive: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/lib/tools.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist."
```

I have checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12588545/11133637 But it's for switching between JDK 1.6 and 1.5, not for minor versions 201 with 101 like this. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

In your project, change the .classpath file to your version of JDK.

If you want to change your version, go to Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs and change the version.