# The type JList is not generic;

Tags: java, ubuntu, virtual-machine, jlist

So I'm working on a project with java in Eclipse. I've been working on it for so long and i only had a few Errors left. They were just some library issues. Now after i've fixed them, suddenly 48 errors popped up. Most of the are the same. One of them is the following:

> The type JList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments >String>

**This Error is on a few lines and I'm just going to add one in here:**

```
private JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listModel);
```

So i've done some research. I've found someone that had the same issue but he could fix it with a java update. So i've tried that to. I've updated Java on my Ubuntu VM to the latest (i think). with the following command:

```
sudo apt upgrade default-jre
```

I don't know what the issue is, so i would be so grateful for someone to help me!

**EDIT:**

So i found out that all the 48 Errors have something to do with the JList. I'm not sure if this helps someone out resolving this.

Comment: Try updating the JDK instead of the JRE

Comment: Can you confirm that JList there is really a `javax.swing.JList`, and not some other class that happens to have the same name?

Comment: @MadProgrammer there was nothing to update.

Comment: @MadProgrammer no it is a `javax.swing.JList`

Comment: java -version  -> do you use 1.6? Or which setting do you use in eclipse?

Comment: @MadProgrammer so i just found out that all the 48 Errors have something to do with the JList.

Comment: Suspicion falls to how Eclipse is configured (and the projects JDK settings)

Comment: @MadProgrammer where do i find the configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong jdk.

You have to change the project-configuration.


"Right-Click on the Project"|Build Path|Configure Build-Path|"Double-Left-Click on JRE System Library" and choose something greater than 1.6

[How to change JDK version for an Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project)