# The method strip() is undefined for the type String

Tags: java, string, function, methods

Trying to use `strip()` method to get rid of white spaces around a string and for some reason `strip()` doesn't work. The error I get is "The method `strip()` is undefined for the type String".

```
String fullAd = "   Hello World   ";
System.out.println(fullAd.strip());
```

Comment: `strip()` is added in java 11. Make sure you are on JDK11 or later version https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()

Answer (score 13):

`strip()` is Java 11 functionality. Either upgrade your version or use `trim()` in older versions.

Comment: Is it not possible to have Java 11 on eclipse IDE? It says it's up to date, I just tried the same code on the intelliJ IDE and it worked tho, thank you.

Comment: @alex207e You need to update the JDK rather than Eclipse, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project

Comment: @alex207e it could be because. Intellij comes up with JDK packaged within it.

Answer (score 0):

The `strip()` funtion is depricated after Java 11. You have to set the Target bytecode version to 11.

For my case i am using intelij. refer the screenshot below
[image: strip() function bytecode version]