# import java.net.http cannot be resolved

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to use HTTP GET and POST in Java but I can't import `java.net.http`. I have very little knowledge about this area, do I need to install something?

Comment: What Java version are you using? And how are you importing whatever class you're trying to import? (since `java.net.http` is a package, not a class)

Comment: Please add an example to show how you are importing the package.

Comment: Could you check which version of Java do you use? The package java.net.http was introduced in Java 11

Comment: I don't know which java version I'm using , an example would be import java.net.http.HttpClient. I'm using Eclipse IDE

Comment: You can check which version of Java do you use on Eclipse. Preferences -> Java -> Compiler (>11) and Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE

Comment: It says jre1.8.0_261

Comment: You need to install Java 11 or up

Comment: I installed jdk 11 but I still have the same problem

Comment: @Insanit you should also configure your OS and/or IDE to use it.

Comment: I configured both the Installed JREs and Execution Environments on Eclipse but it still gives me a warning saying current version is 1.8

Comment: Open your pom file and check which version of Java appears

Comment: Not sure if it's the right one but I found 
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\server\jvm.dll in the Configuration

Comment: [Check the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is connected with the version of Java/JRE that exist in your system because the package "**java.net.http**" was included in Java 11 or up.

Try to download a new version of java from one of these sites [Oracle JDK 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html) or [Open JDK](https://openjdk.java.net/install/)

After installing the new version of Java check that Eclipse uses the correct one. To do this in your Eclipse go to **Preferences -> Java -> Compiler** and select 11, also go to **Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE** and add the new JRE

Comment: Thanks I got it to work after changing the line under -vm in eclipse.ini to the correct latest version of java that I installed.

Comment: Great, enjoy all the features of Java 11 :-)

Comment: @AndresSacco if im using Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 2, Wher i can install JRE?